# can I use dblink in two tables in clause inner join in oracle?

Tags: oracle, inner-join, dblink

For example :

```
select t1.*  
  from tabla1@dblink t1
  inner join tabla2@dblink t2
    on t1.campo1=t2.campo1
```

Comment: Yes, that should work fine.

Comment: You can, yes.  Did you try it?  Did you encounter an error?  Or some other problem?  Depending on the actual query, it can be very difficult for the optimizer to generate reasonable plans for distributed queries.  If you've got a performance problem, you may want to create a view on the remote database that does the join and query that remote view from your system.

Comment: thanks  the problem was solved